# How to convert string into datetime format?

Tags: community, datetime

Hello Everyone I'm new in sales force  and I want to change datetime format so that first of all I got datetime and after that I have convert it to string with different format . Now I want to again convert this into datetime format but this give error invalid date time . my code is here .....

```
DateTime startDT2 = DateTime.newInstance(selectedDate.addDays(1), initialEndTime);
system.debug('select dt2>>>'+ startDT2); **output**=2014-12-09 8:00:00

String myDate = startDT2.format('M/d/yyyy h:mm a'); 
system.debug('select mydate>>>'+ myDate); **output**=12/9/2014 1:00 AM
Datetime dt = Datetime.valueOf(myDate);
system.debug('date_string >>>'+ dt);             **output**=invalid date/time
```

So please anyone tell me about this or solve my problem .I'm really thank full for whom.

Answer (score 3):

Please use **parse()** method instead of **valueOf()** method.

```
Datetime dt = Datetime.parse(myDate);
```

Please refer for more details on DateTime Methods: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_parse

UPDATE:

I've provided the code for you which I tested.

```
DateTime startDT2 = DateTime.now();
system.debug('select dt2>>>'+ startDT2);
String myDate = startDT2.format('M/d/yyyy h:mm a'); 
system.debug('select mydate>>>'+ myDate);
Datetime dt = Datetime.parse(myDate);
system.debug('date_string >>>'+ dt);
```

The result is `16:18:50:041 USER_DEBUG [7]|DEBUG|date_string >>>2014-12-09 10:48:00`

Comment: I have already use this but I have same problem. basically I want to change my date time format i.e. suppose my date time 09-12-2014 11:00 PM convert into 09-12-2014 23:00 or vice verse .

Comment: Please check the Update section of my answer. I used the format given by you. It got me the result successfully. Please re-check your code once!

Comment: I'm not getting the time part after datetime.parse. e.g. `select mydate>>>12/9/2014 5:00 AM` after parse is `date_string >>>2014-12-09 00:00:00`.

Comment: Please add your entire debug logs for your code above!

Comment: +1 vignex: my bad. I was using `date.today()`. Updated it with `datetime.now()` and it works. offcourse, date.today() makes the time part 00:00:00 . :)

Comment: This is absolutely right but @Vignex but I don't know why this give error :VF_PAGE_MESSAGE|Invalid date/time: 12/9/2014 8:00 PM

Comment: @rahulsharma Can you please update your code and provide debug logs as well? Please check the value of startDT2 once.